# Simple Pivot Table with Month and text data Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

How do you create a simple Pivot Table in Dynamic SQL with the following data:

```
 ID Month   AssignmentMonth Designation
 1  5            May         Joe Blow
 2  5            May         Available
 3  5            May         Available
 4  5            May         Available
 5  6            June        Carry over
 6  6            June        Christopher Freeberg
 7  6            June        Ringo Starr
 8  6            June        Robert L Testcustomer
 9  7            July        Carry over
10  7            July        Carry over
11  7            July        Carry over
12  7            July        Carry over
13  8            August      Available
14  8            August      Carry over
15  8            August      Carry over
16  8            August      Carry over
```

So when it is done it Looks like the below example:

```
May               June                 July                 August

Joe Blow         Carry Over            Carry over          Available
Available        Christopher Freeburg  Carry over          Carry over
Available        Ringo Starr           Carry over          Carry over
Available        Robert L Testcustomer Carry over          Carry over
```

This is my attempt but it does produce the correct results.It only returns one row.

```
   August        July       June                    May
   Carry over   Carry over  Robert L Testcustomer   Joe Blow

    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +   QUOTENAME(AssignmentMonth) 
                from @CardAssigns
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'') 
SET @query = 'WITH PivotData AS
(
SELECT   Designation, AssignmentMonth      
FROM    #Temp1
)
SELECT  '+ @cols +'
FROM PivotData
PIVOT
(
MAX(Designation)
FOR AssignmentMonth
IN ( '+ @cols +' )
) as PIVOTResult'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below uses dynamic query and a ROW_NUMBER to line up the values as you described.

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    ID INT,
    Month INT,
     AssignmentMonth VARCHAR(50),
     Designation VARCHAR(50)

)
INSERT #Data VALUES
(1,5,'May','Joe Blow'),
(2,5,'May','Available'),
(3,5,'May','Available'),
(4,5,'May','Available'),
(5,6,'June','Carry over'),
(6,6,'June','Christopher Freeberg'),
(7,6,'June','Ringo Starr'),
(8,6,'June','Robert L Testcustomer'),
(9,7,'July','Carry over'),
(10,7,'July','Carry over'),
(11,7,'July','Carry over'),
(12,7,'July','Carry over'),
(13,8,'August','Available'),
(14,8,'August','Carry over'),
(15,8,'August','Carry over'),
(16,8,'August','Carry over')

DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR(MAX) =
    SUBSTRING((
        SELECT
            ',[' + AssignmentMonth + ']' AS [text()]
        FROM #Data
        GROUP BY AssignmentMonth
        ORDER BY MIN(ID)
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 2, 4000)
DECLARE @ColumnAggs VARCHAR(MAX) =
    SUBSTRING((
        SELECT
            ',MAX([' + AssignmentMonth + ']) AS [' + AssignmentMonth + ']' AS [text()]
        FROM #Data
        GROUP BY AssignmentMonth
        ORDER BY MIN(ID)
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 2, 4000)

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) =
    'SELECT ' + @ColumnAggs + ' FROM ('
    + 'SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Month ORDER BY ID) AS RowId, ' + @ColumnList
    + 'FROM #Data D PIVOT (MAX(Designation) FOR AssignmentMonth IN (' + @ColumnList + ')) P'
    + ') T GROUP BY RowId'
    PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Output

```
May                            June                           July                           August
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
Joe Blow                       Carry over                     Carry over                     Available
Available                      Christopher Freeberg           Carry over                     Carry over
Available                      Ringo Starr                    Carry over                     Carry over
Available                      Robert L Testcustomer          Carry over                     Carry over
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query, is that the pivot query doesn't have a column to group by. The `pivot` table operator automatically `GROUP BY` the column(s) that are not listed in the part `MAX(Designation) FOR AssignmentMonth IN ...` which comes from the anchor query, so in your query you have only two columns coming from the anchor query `Designation` and `AssignmentMonth`, so your query doesn't have any extra column to group by so that it gives you the `MAX(Designation)` which is only one row. But, you can do a workaround by adding one more column to group by with, and since you can't group by neither `ID` nor `Month`, you can add a row number column and it will give you the desired results, something like this:

```
SET @query = 'WITH PivotData AS
(
  SELECT   
    Designation, 
    AssignmentMonth, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY   AssignmentMonth ORDER BY ID) AS RN
  FROM   CardAssigns
)
SELECT  '+ @cols +'
FROM PivotData
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Designation)
  FOR AssignmentMonth
  IN ( '+ @cols +' )
) as PIVOTResult';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b34b/10)

This will give you:

```
|     August |       July |                  June |       May |
|------------|------------|-----------------------|-----------|
|  Available | Carry over |            Carry over |  Joe Blow |
| Carry over | Carry over |  Christopher Freeberg | Available |
| Carry over | Carry over |           Ringo Starr | Available |
| Carry over | Carry over | Robert L Testcustomer | Available |
```